# How to convert a CVXPY result into numpy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, cvxopt, cvxpy

I have got an optimization problem defined in cvxpy, but want to work with the result in my code in numpy afterwards - how can I convert it from cvxpy into numpy?

It is of type

```
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
```

If I want to plot it to see the result, matplotlib shows only a blue area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.view.html seems to have all you need

numpy's `view` can be used (afaik) in any which way you can use numpy's `array` directly.

It makes sense to "convert" to a numpy array if you want to get a **copy** of data:

```
y
matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int16)

type(y)
numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix    


n = numpy.array(y)
n[1,2] = 999

n
array([[  1,   0,   0,   0,   2,   0,   0,   0],
       [  3,   0, 999,   0,   4,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=int16)

y
matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int16)
```